# Limitations for controlling files with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, download

Please excuse me for not being good at English because I do not live in an English-speaking country.

I am student, and I want to make code for file encryption and download that file with jquery(in client side).

I solved it, but I have some problems.

When I upload file for encrypting file that has big size,
my site is crashed.
(My code will be applied to a simple homepage.)

When I run that process in firefox or icedragon browser, I can see error that 'allocation size overflow'.

Can you tell me why that problem happened?

The code I wrote is below and the reference address is [here](https://tutorialzine.com/2013/11/javascript-file-encrypter).

```
$(function(){

var body = $('body'),
    stage = $('#stage'),
    back = $('a.back');

/* Step 1 */

$('#step1 .encrypt').click(function(){
    body.attr('class', 'encrypt');

    // Go to step 2
    step(2);
});

$('#step1 .decrypt').click(function(){
    body.attr('class', 'decrypt');
    step(2);
});


/* Step 2 */


$('#step2 .button').click(function(){
    // Trigger the file browser dialog
    $(this).parent().find('input').click();
});


// Set up events for the file inputs

var file = null;

$('#step2').on('change', '#encrypt-input', function(e){

    // Has a file been selected?

    if(e.target.files.length!=1){
        alert('Please select a file to encrypt!');
        return false;
    }

    file = e.target.files[0];

    /*if(file.size > 1024*1024*50){
        alert('Please choose files smaller than 50mb, otherwise you may crash your browser. \nThis WARNING is for you.');
        return;
    }*/

    step(3);
});

$('#step2').on('change', '#decrypt-input', function(e){

    if(e.target.files.length!=1){
        alert('Please select a file to decrypt!');
        return false;
    }

    file = e.target.files[0];
    step(3);
});


/* Step 3 */


$('a.button.process').click(function(){

    var input = $(this).parent().find('input[type=password]'),
        a = $('#step4 a.download'),
        password = input.val();

    input.val('');

    if(password.length<5){
        alert('Please choose a longer password!');
        return;
    }

    // The HTML5 FileReader object will allow us to read the
    // contents of the  selected file.

    var reader = new FileReader();

    if(body.hasClass('encrypt')){

        // Encrypt the file!

        reader.onload = function(e){

            // Use the CryptoJS library and the AES cypher to encrypt the
            // contents of the file, held in e.target.result, with the password
            var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(e.target.result, password);


            var encryptedFileArray = [encrypted];
            var blob = 'Blob Data';
            var fileName = file.name + '.encrypted';

            if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
            } else {

                var blobEncrypted = new Blob(encryptedFileArray, { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

                var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blobEncrypted);
                $(a).attr({
                    'download': file.name + '.encrypted',
                    'href': blobUrl
                });
            }

            // The download attribute will cause the contents of the href
            // attribute to be downloaded when clicked. The download attribute
            // also holds the name of the file that is offered for download.
            step(4);
        };

        // This will encode the contents of the file into a data-uri.
        // It will trigger the onload handler above, with the result

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    else {

        // Decrypt it!

        reader.onload = function(e){

            var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(e.target.result, password).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1);

            if(!/^data:/.test(decrypted)){
                alert("Invalid pass phrase or file! Please try again.");
                return false;
            }


            var url = decrypted; 
            var userAgent = navigator.userAgent; 
            var filename = file.name.replace('.encrypted',''); 
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.onload = function () {
                $(a).attr({
                    'download': filename,
                    'href': window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response) // xhr.response is a blob
                });
            };
            xhr.open('GET', url);
            xhr.send();

            step(4);
        };

        reader.readAsText(file);
    }
});


/* The back button */


back.click(function(){

    // Reinitialize the hidden file inputs,
    // so that they don't hold the selection
    // from last time

    $('#step2 input[type=file]').replaceWith(function(){
        return $(this).clone();
    });

    step(1);
});


// Helper function that moves the viewport to the correct step div

function step(i){

    if(i == 1){
        back.fadeOut();
    }
    else{
        back.fadeIn();
    }

    // Move the #stage div. Changing the top property will trigger
    // a css transition on the element. i-1 because we want the
    // steps to start from 1:

    stage.css('top',(-(i-1)*100)+'%');
}
```

});

Comment: what is your server side language? is it PHP?

Answer (score 0):

```
xhr.open('GET', url);
```

you are using GET method. maybe is better using POST instead.
what is your server side language? is it PHP?
if that is PHP, should be better check the file upload size in "php.ini" file.

Comment: I didn't use server side language. I just used jquery for file encryption and downloading.